# Redux Remove one item from cart

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've build an app in `react-native` and i'm using `react-redux` to store data in my cart.

Currently when I add a product lets say apple to my cart. My cart will contain 1x apple and if I add the same product to my cart I will have 2x apple.

---

**Problem**

But if I try to remove 1x apple my cart removes all the apples in my cart.

---

**Question**

How can I remove the item in my cart by -1?

**cartitems.js**

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state.filter(cartItem=>cartItem.id !== 
                action.payload.id )
```

**CartProducts.js component**

```
<View key={products.index} style={styles.appels}>
      <View style={styles.iconContainer}> 
           <Icon name={products.item.icon} color="#DD016B" size={25} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.text}>
           <Text style={styles.name}>
                {products.item.name}
           </Text>

           <Text style={styles.price}>
                € {products.item.price}
           </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress(products.item)} > 
              <Icon style={styles.button} name="ios-remove" color="white" size={25} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
     </View>
```

**CartScreen.js**

```
<Products products={appels} onPress={this.props.addItemToCart}/>
```

**CartScreen.js | handeling removing product from cart**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        removeItem:(product) => dispatch ({
            type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , payload: product
        })  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are keeping duplicates of the same product in the state when multiple copies of the same product are added. You should therefore only filter the first match instead of all matches:

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART': {
  const index = state.findIndex(item => item.id === action.payload.id);
  return state.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
}
```

This should get it to work while keeping your current design.

However, if the user removes a duplicated product from the bottom of the list, the UI might not be intuitive as the first copy of the product in the list will be removed from the UI instead, hence you might want to adjust your `removeItem` action payload to contain the index of the product to be removed instead of the product object.

A better approach might be to use a `qty` variable to indicate multiple copies, which will reduce the state size and make it easier to display a quantity column on the cart screen (instead of displaying duplicated products):

```
case 'ADD_ITEM_TO_CART':
  if (state.some(item => item.id === action.payload.id)) {
    // increase qty if item already exists in cart
    return state.map(item => (item.id === action.payload.id ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 } : item));
  }
  return [...state, { ...action.payload, qty: 1 }]; // else add the new item to cart

case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
  return state
    .map(item => (item.id === action.payload.id ? { ...item, qty: item.qty - 1 } : item))
    .filter(item => item.qty > 0);
```

Your `CartScreen.js` will also need to be modified accordingly if you use this new design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there anywhere where I can find how to make the modifications? For example this changes the way I add to my cart and remove. Could you explain how this function would work as wel?

Comment: You can use my suggestion of filtering by index if you want to keep your current functions/UI. If you want to change to storing quantity instead of duplicates, you need to display the quantity column and allow user to modify the quantity, and the reducer will set the matching item's `qty` to the action payload's specified qty.

Comment: I've successfully used your code in my mine, but how do I update the qty live in my cart screen? I need to reload the page to see the result?

Comment: If the rendered qty value comes directly from the connected redux store, the screen should re-render with the updated value automatically when the store updates.

Comment: I've rendered it like this `{products.item.qty}` and `connect` it to the `store` yet it seems static.

Comment: Try debug it to see if the updated qty is being re-rendered. Maybe you are doing direct state mutation. Can't really help much without seeing the full code.

Comment: Alright, Thank you for the help! :) If I can't debug it I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

When doing

> return state.filter(cartItem=>cartItem.id !== action.payload.id )

You are basically saying, return everything but this cartItem specificaly.

That is not what you want. You want to give :

- A quantity to remove in the payload.
- The id of the product.

So here is your action :

```
dispatch({type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , payload: {product, qty} })
```

Then you have to find your item and update it's quantity :

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':

      const updatedProductList = state.productList.map( (product) => {
          if(product.id === payload.product.id){ // this is the item we care about
            return {
              ...product, // this will avoid a state mutation
              qty : product.qty - payload.qty // update the qty
            }
          }else { // just return the element as it is
            return cartItem
          }
        })

    return updatedCartItemList;
break;
default :
 return state
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When adding

`dispatch({type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART' , payload: {product, qty} })` it says `qty` is undefined?  Does that happen beause i need to add `qty ` when adding a product?

Comment: I tried adding it to `add_item` but also get can't find variable `qty`

Comment: I declared an variable in the `CartScreen.js` `const qty= null` and now get a new error `undefined is not an object (evaluating state.productList.map)` in cartItems.
I'm now trying to figure out wat is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
case UNFAVORITE: {
      return {
        favorite: [
          ...state.favorite.filter(favorite => favorite !== action.payload),
        ],
      };
    }
```

simply do this to UNFAVORITE

Answer (score -1):

Well, you may need to pass either quantity or increment/decrement flag in your action payload.

your action creator may accept parameter for increment/decrement

```
const updateItem = dispatch=>(increment=true)=>{
  dispatch({type:'UPDATE_IN_CART' , payload: product, increment})
}
```

Now in your reducer

```
case 'UPDATE_IN_CART':{
   const {increment, payload}= action;  //ES6 destructing
   const updatedCart = state.map((cartItem)=>{
      if(cartItem.id !== payload.id )){
          cartItem.quantity = increment?cartItem.quantity+1:cartItem.quantity-1 //will handle increment/decrement; 
      }
      return cartItem;
   })
   return updatedCart;
}
```

Comment: This mutates directly.

Comment: I think this will cause a state mutation 

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array

I think, you must return it using a spread operator,

Comment: filter and map aren't mutating functions, they work on the copy of the array.

Comment: The array will not be mutated, but it's elements will - it's still a mutation.